# How to determine if given “complex” time complexity is $O(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, big-o-notation

If a given time complexity, such as these:

1. $(n + \log n) * \sqrt{n+\log n}$
2. $n * (200 + \log^2 n)$
3. $(7+n^3)\log(n^5)$

is not determinable by just looking at it whether is it in class $O(n^2)$ or not, how do I decide? If a time complexity is given, and in it there are more types of expressions (exponential, logarithmic, polinomial, ... ) how do I decide which one determines the $O(n^2)$ or $O(n\log n)$ or ... complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you can replace them by $n$. For example, in $F_1(n) = (n+\log(n))\times \sqrt{n+\log n}$, replace $\log(n)$ by $n$. So, $F_1(n) \leqslant 2n \sqrt{2n}$ and it means $F_1(n) = O(n\sqrt{n})$. Also, in multiplication or summation, you can ignore constants (not all the time in power functions). Hence, $F_2(n) = n \times (200 + \log^2(n)) = \Theta(n
\log^2(n))$. Or in $F_3(n) = (7 + n^3) \log(n^5) = 5 \times (7 + n^3) \log(n) = \Theta(n^3 \log(n))$ (as $\log(n^c) = c \log(n)$).